# Do I Need to Call .AcceptChanges() before .Update() After a delete Operation

Tags: c#, .net, ms-access, ado.net

Hello I'm making a small database application with MS Access database. I add to database from a textbox and delete from a database using a combobox and showing the database in datagridview adding seems to work fine except for autoincrement not showing before a restart and i cant delete because when i call update after deletion it gives me a DBConcurrencyException i tried to add acceptchanges before update and that is not gave any error but the changes didn't saved to database.

Here is my two questions

- How to make autoincrement show without restarting application.(this is not so important i can hide ID column)
- And most importantly how to make deletes work.

additionally i use OleDbCommandBuilder for update methods

Comment: .AcceptChanges() tells the dataset/datatable that there are no more changes to be persisted to the database. So: .Update() after .AcceptChanges() has no effect in database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 queries

> AutoIncrements: Please refer [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms971502.aspx) which states that you should perform a select query to fill the db autogenerated values back into the dataset tables.
>
> Regarding the deletes, just delete the row in the datatable, its rowstate will be marked as `Deleted`. When you update this to the DB using adapter, it will find the rows to be deleted and will perform the deletion in the db accordingly. When you call acceptchanges(), it will mark that all rows are in the `original` state and will result in no db updates.

**EDIT**

The DBConcurrency exception occurs when there is no effect of a CRUD operation. for more details refer [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/system.data.dbconcurrencyexception.aspx)